# ext js how to fit each component using border layout

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I'm using `border` layout and I want to make each region to fit its container. I always see a scroll despite I use `fit` layout for all items except container panel.

My Ext JS version: **4.2.1**

**Here's what I tried:**

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    region: 'west'
        ......
});

var chartContainer = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', { // a panel contains a pie chart
    region: 'center'
});


var mainPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', { // my main container panel
    layout: 'border',
    items: [grid, chartContainer]
});


Ext.create('Ext.Window', { // I want to render this main panel inside a window
    layout: 'fit',
    width: 950,
    height: 500,
    items: [mainPanel]
});
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: So, you want `grid` and `chartContainer` to be fit inside `mainPanel`? Because you are applying a border layout to them. The fit layout is only being applied to `mainPanel` (it will be fit to the window it is inside)

Comment: @forgivenson yes this is what exactly I'm looking. So how can I make all child items to fit its parents?

Answer (score 0):

The items should automatically fit their border layout regions.

I just complemented your code with a few things to make it work (example grid data, calling `.show()` on the main window etc.) and ran it on [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com) with Ext JS 4.2.1 without any problems, especially there are no undesired scroll bars.

Here is the full example source code:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Border Layout',

    launch: function() {
        // create the Data Store
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'Person',
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['firstName', 'lastName'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                data: [
                    ["Anton", "Mainzel"],
                    ["Bertie", "Mainzel"],
                    ["Connie", "Mainzel"],
                    ["Det", "Mainzel"],
                    ["Eddie", "Mainzel"]
                ],
                reader: {
                    type: 'array'
                }
            }
        });

        var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            region: 'west',
            width: 120,
            split: true,
            store: store,
            columns: [{
                text: "First",
                width: 120,
                dataIndex: 'firstName'
            }, {
                text: "Last",
                width: 120,
                dataIndex: 'lastName'
            }]
        });

        var chartContainer = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', { // a panel contains a pie chart
            region: 'center',
            bodyStyle: 'background-color:green; color:white',
            html: '<p>Center</p>'
        });


        var mainPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', { // my main container panel
            layout: 'border',
            items: [grid, chartContainer]
        });


        Ext.create('Ext.Window', { // I want to render this main panel inside a window
            layout: 'fit',
            width: 950,
            height: 500,
            items: [mainPanel]
        }).show();

    }
});
```